# How to get 2012 Chevy Equinox to recognize my Evo 3d?

Tags: htc-evo-3d

When I plug my Evo 3d into my 2012 Chevy Equinox (w/color touch radio), the Equinox does not recognize the phone. I'm using a micro USB cable to connect my phone to the vehicle. After plugging it in, the Evo 3d starts charging, but the Equinox does not show any available USB connection.
Iphone 4 is able to plugin and get recognized just fine.

How can I get the Equinox to recognize the Evo 3d so I can play audio from my phone through the Equinox stereo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have noticed a lot of vehicles that do not recognize any android devices but they do recognize iphones/ipods. This is something the manufacture has to add support for. These manufacturers usually use a proprietary system in the vehicle and they don't seem to think anyone uses anything besides an iphone or ipod.

You may be able to use bluetooth to transmit the audio from your device to your vehicles stereo.

Answer (score 3):

On most android phones SD card storage cannot be used by both the phone itself and another device simultaneously. So for the Evo 3d to be available to your Equinox' player you might have to do something like tap on `Turn on USB-Storage` (not sure if this is your case) or choose `Disk Drive` when prompted about `Connection Type` on it. During this time the apps that you've moved to SD card cant be run, neither can you browse the SD card contents from your phone.

BTW, if your vehicle supports bluetooth with A2DP profile, that might be more convenient.